# Pagination works in counting and dividing, but links don't change records

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Trying to apply this code. It seems to count the number of records, but when you click the links to switch the page the url seems to pick up the GET variable, but nothing happens. The same 2 records from the first page stay there.

**Here is the Page**

```
<?php     


require("base.php");
include_once('pagination.class.php');



$items = 2;
$page = 1;


if(isset($_GET['page']) and is_numeric($_GET['page']) and $page = $_GET['page'])
         $limit = " LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$items).",$items";
      else
         $limit = " LIMIT $items";

         $aux = Mysql_Fetch_Assoc(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM claiminfo WHERE ( privacyset='1') "));

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, claiminfo.claim_id AS id FROM claiminfo LEFT JOIN ( claim_pics ) ON ( claiminfo.claim_id = claim_pics.claim_id )  WHERE (    
         privacyset='1') && (picID IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY claiminfo.ts DESC".$limit);

        if($aux['total']>0){
            $p = new pagination;
            $p->Items($aux['total']);
            $p->limit($items);
            $p->target("/gallery/");
            $p->currentPage($page);
            $p->calculate();
            $p->changeClass("pagination");


            $p->show();



                      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) { 


                                        $namelocation =      $row['namelocation'];
                                        $claimholder =   $row['claimholder'];
                                        $occasion =      $row['occasion'];
                                        $geotag =    $row['geotag'];
                                        $lat =   $row['lat'] ;
                                        $lng =   $row['lng'];
                                        $claim_id = $row['id']; 
                                        $img = $row['location'];



echo "


<div class='clearfix draft product' style='margin-top: 30px;
float: left;
padding: 17px 4px 0px 20px;
margin-right: 30px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #F092A1;
'>
<div class='photo' style='float: left;'>
<a href='/view/?claim_id=$claim_id'><img alt='' width='130' height='55' src='$img' /></a>
</div>
<div class='basic' style='float: left; margin-left: 30px;width:280px;border:1px;'>
<h3><a href='/view/?claim_id=$claim_id'>$namelocation</a></h3>


<p style='color: black;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20px;
float: left;
'>
$occasion
</p>
</div>
<div class='stats' style='margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 160px;'>
<div class='stat'>
<span class='unit'>
<b>$claimholder</b>
<br />
</span>
</div>
<div class='stat'>
<b>Lat:</b>
<span class='unit'>
$lat
</span>
</div>
<div class='stat'>
<b>Lng:</b>
<span class='unit'>
$lng
</span>

</div>
<br />

</div>
</div>
";




                      }




        }else
            echo"There no are records to paginate.";


                       ?>
```

**Here is the script**

```
<?php
class pagination{
/*
Script Name: *Digg Style Paginator Class
Script URI: http://www.mis-algoritmos.com/2007/05/27/digg-style-pagination-class/
Description: Class in PHP that allows to use a pagination like a digg or sabrosus style.
Script Version: 0.4
Author: Victor De la Rocha
Author URI: http://www.mis-algoritmos.com
*/
        /*Default values*/
        var $total_pages = -1;//items
        var $limit = null;
        var $target = ""; 
        var $page = 1;
        var $adjacents = 2;
        var $showCounter = false;
        var $className = "pagination";
        var $parameterName = "page";
        var $urlF = false;//urlFriendly

        /*Buttons next and previous*/
        var $nextT = "Next";
        var $nextI = "&#187;"; //&#9658;
        var $prevT = "Previous";
        var $prevI = "&#171;"; //&#9668;

        /*****/
        var $calculate = false;

        #Total items
        function items($value){$this->total_pages = (int) $value;}

        #how many items to show per page
        function limit($value){$this->limit = (int) $value;}

        #Page to sent the page value
        function target($value){$this->target = $value;}

        #Current page
        function currentPage($value){$this->page = (int) $value;}

        #How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side of the current page?
        function adjacents($value){$this->adjacents = (int) $value;}

        #show counter?
        function showCounter($value=""){$this->showCounter=($value===true)?true:false;}

        #to change the class name of the pagination div
        function changeClass($value=""){$this->className=$value;}

        function nextLabel($value){$this->nextT = $value;}
        function nextIcon($value){$this->nextI = $value;}
        function prevLabel($value){$this->prevT = $value;}
        function prevIcon($value){$this->prevI = $value;}

        #to change the class name of the pagination div
        function parameterName($value=""){$this->parameterName=$value;}

        #to change urlFriendly
        function urlFriendly($value="%"){
                if(eregi('^ *$',$value)){
                        $this->urlF=false;
                        return false;
                    }
                $this->urlF=$value;
            }

        var $pagination;

        function pagination(){}
        function show(){
                if(!$this->calculate)
                    if($this->calculate())
                        echo "<div class=\"$this->className\">$this->pagination</div>\n";
            }
        function getOutput(){
                if(!$this->calculate)
                    if($this->calculate())
                        return "<div class=\"$this->className\">$this->pagination</div>\n";
            }
        function get_pagenum_link($id){
                if(strpos($this->target,'?')===false)
                        if($this->urlF)
                                return str_replace($this->urlF,$id,$this->target);
                            else
                                return "$this->target?$this->parameterName=$id";
                    else
                        return "$this->target&$this->parameterName=$id";
            }

        function calculate(){
                $this->pagination = "";
                $this->calculate == true;
                $error = false;
                if($this->urlF and $this->urlF != '%' and strpos($this->target,$this->urlF)===false){
                        //Es necesario especificar el comodin para sustituir
                        echo "Especificaste un wildcard para sustituir, pero no existe en el target<br />";
                        $error = true;
                    }elseif($this->urlF and $this->urlF == '%' and strpos($this->target,$this->urlF)===false){
                        echo "Es necesario especificar en el target el comodin % para sustituir el número de página<br />";
                        $error = true;
                    }

                if($this->total_pages < 0){
                        echo "It is necessary to specify the <strong>number of pages</strong> (\$class->items(1000))<br />";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                if($this->limit == null){
                        echo "It is necessary to specify the <strong>limit of items</strong> to show per page (\$class->limit(10))<br />";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                if($error)return false;

                $n = trim($this->nextT.' '.$this->nextI);
                $p = trim($this->prevI.' '.$this->prevT);

                /* Setup vars for query. */
                if($this->page) 
                    $start = ($this->page - 1) * $this->limit;             //first item to display on this page
                else
                    $start = 0;                                //if no page var is given, set start to 0

                /* Setup page vars for display. */
                $prev = $this->page - 1;                            //previous page is page - 1
                $next = $this->page + 1;                            //next page is page + 1
                $lastpage = ceil($this->total_pages/$this->limit);        //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
                $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                        //last page minus 1

                /* 
                    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
                    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
                */

                if($lastpage > 1){
                        if($this->page){
                                //anterior button
                                if($this->page > 1)
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($prev)."\" class=\"prev\">$p</a>";
                                    else
                                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">$p</span>";
                            }
                        //pages 
                        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($this->adjacents * 2)){//not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++){
                                        if ($counter == $this->page)
                                                $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                            else
                                                $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($counter)."\">$counter</a>";
                                    }
                            }
                        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($this->adjacents * 2)){//enough pages to hide some
                                //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                                if($this->page < 1 + ($this->adjacents * 2)){
                                        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($this->adjacents * 2); $counter++){
                                                if ($counter == $this->page)
                                                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                                    else
                                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($counter)."\">$counter</a>";
                                            }
                                        $this->pagination .= "...";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($lpm1)."\">$lpm1</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($lastpage)."\">$lastpage</a>";
                                    }
                                //in middle; hide some front and some back
                                elseif($lastpage - ($this->adjacents * 2) > $this->page && $this->page > ($this->adjacents * 2)){
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link(1)."\">1</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link(2)."\">2</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "...";
                                        for ($counter = $this->page - $this->adjacents; $counter <= $this->page + $this->adjacents; $counter++)
                                            if ($counter == $this->page)
                                                    $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                                else
                                                    $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($counter)."\">$counter</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "...";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($lpm1)."\">$lpm1</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($lastpage)."\">$lastpage</a>";
                                    }
                                //close to end; only hide early pages
                                else{
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link(1)."\">1</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link(2)."\">2</a>";
                                        $this->pagination .= "...";
                                        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($this->adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                            if ($counter == $this->page)
                                                    $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                                else
                                                    $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($counter)."\">$counter</a>";
                                    }
                            }
                        if($this->page){
                                //siguiente button
                                if ($this->page < $counter - 1)
                                        $this->pagination .= "<a href=\"".$this->get_pagenum_link($next)."\" class=\"next\">$n</a>";
                                    else
                                        $this->pagination .= "<span class=\"disabled\">$n</span>";
                                    if($this->showCounter)$this->pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination_data\">($this->total_pages Pages)</div>";
                            }
                    }

                return true;
            }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone have a hunch.

FYI: It is on a Wordpress, but this is totally a custom mysql code. I am not calling posts or anything. I was wondering that perhaps Wordpress .htaccess could be preventing it from working.

Comment: Aren't you getting any warning? Because the pagination class itself should throw a few.

Comment: if i were you i would echo $query first.... then you can if your if statement is working fine or not

Comment: I found out what it was. Wordpress uses the paramater ?page and ?p= to indicate global variables from the Wordpress data base. I simply changes the name of the parameter to "?gala= and everything seems to work fine.

The only thing now is when I echo the GET variable the number 2 becomes 22 and 3 becomes 33, but the paginations works like it should. Thanks.